# ActivityNotFoundException in generating qrcode

Tags: android, android-activity, qr-code

I am trying to generate qrcode via intent, but I'm always getting `ActivityNotFoundException`. I  have my core.jar in my lib.

Here is my code:

```
intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE");
    intent.putExtra("ENCODE_TYPE", "TEXT_TYPE");
    intent.putExtra("ENCODE_DATA", "Hello World!");
    startActivity(intent);
```

And here is the log:

```
10-12 20:47:09.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1347): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-12 20:47:09.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1347): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sampleqrcode/com.example.sampleqrcode.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] (has extras) }
10-12 20:47:09.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
10-12 20:47:09.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
10-12 20:47:09.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
10-12 20:47:09.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
10-12 20:47:09.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-12 20:47:09.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-12 20:47:09.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-12 20:47:09.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-12 20:47:09.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-12 20:47:09.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-12 20:47:09.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-12 20:47:09.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-12 20:47:09.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1347): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] (has extras) }
10-12 20:47:09.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1512)
10-12 20:47:09.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
10-12 20:47:09.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
10-12 20:47:09.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
10-12 20:47:09.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at com.example.sampleqrcode.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
10-12 20:47:09.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
10-12 20:47:09.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-12 20:47:09.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
10-12 20:47:09.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1347):     ... 11 more
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

1. import a zxing library project in your workspace from [here](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/tree/master/android).
2. create a new project from a library project.It will work fine.

   Also you can visit this [link](http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/) for implementation.

Comment: This is irrelevant to integrating by Intent, and not recommended anyway. The answer is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

This means that Barcode Scanner is not installed. You are responsible for catching `ActivityNotFoundException` and handling it, like prompting the user to install it.

Better still, use the `android-integration` code in the original zxing project. It's two classes, and it wraps up all of the details like this in a simple API. http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Comment: Do I need Barcode Scanner to show the QRCode? I'm sorry for my dumb questions.

Comment: Oops! Now, I'm aware of about this `Exception` Actually, i thought its because of `.jar` file not imported properly. Thanks for your information.